# KNN intuition based on graph

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

Question: Estimate the error rate of the one-nearest-neighbor (1-NN) classifier for this problem using
leave-one-out cross validation. (That is, using S-fold cross validation with S equal to the
number of training cases, in which each training case is predicted using all the other training
cases.)

[image]

Could someone walk me through the logic in this question? It is supposed to help us understand the intuition of how KNN works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you guessed it right- this is usually an example to show how overfitting/underfitting varies with choice of k.

If you choose k=1, the algorithm will pick the neighbor as the point itself and have a extremely overfit decision boundary. When you do a leave one out cv the error you will thus obtain will be high.

If you choose k=(no of data points), the decision boundary will be the average line for all your data points (extreme underfitting). In this case too you will obtain a high error.